# How to open url source code?

Tags: python

I try to write code, that can open url connection and read text from the response. I've tried:

```
import urllib

urllib.urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345')
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

What's wrong with my code and what is the solution to the problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as "url source code". Do you mean you wish to make an HTTP request to a specified URL and return back the response's message body as a string? For a typical web site, this means you would receive an HTML document as a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are on Python 3.x but using code that only works on 2.x.

In Python 3.x, the `urlopen` function is contained in [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request):

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen
<function urlopen at 0x020DA7C8>
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

I think this does everything you want:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php?nothing=12345').read()
print(page)
```

Comment: @RainTenno - I'm saying that I think you need to import the `urllib.request` module to use the `urlopen` function.  Right now, you are just importing `urllib`.

Comment: I just don't understand how this code works. Can you write a code that will open my url and converts source code into str?

Answer (score 2):

Try "requests".  It is much easier to work with.

http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/linkedlist.php', params={
    'nothing':'12345'
})
print r.text
```

Comment: Oleksandr, are you using pip?  'pip install requests' should do it.